# Custom View Clicks not being Recorded

Tags: firebase-test-lab, android-espresso-recorder

When running either a Robo Script Recorder or Espresso Test Recorder, when clicking on a custom view, the click action is not being recorded.   I've checked to make sure that the custom onTouchListener is calling performClick() when Action.UP is called.   Is there something else that needs to be done as well to make sure the recorders pickup the click actions from custom views?

Answer (score 0):

For those that might run into this issue in the future, if you have a custom OnTouchListener that is being assigned to the view, make sure that the listener doesn't consume the event (i.e. return true).   It should always return false.  Also if you call performClick() as part of the ACTION_UP, make sure you break out of the switch for this case and not let it fall through to the bottom if you have another action case to be handled after it.

If you consume the events, then you interrupt the PerformClick#run() flow for the view, and th Espresso Recorder and Robo Script recorders can not register the events.

This information came from the Firebase Slack channel.